# Most efficient way of deleting records from a view with multiple base tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, view

I need write a VB function that deletes all records from the base tables of a view that have been initialised with default values/default constraint key values.

My understanding is that the only way to do this is to delete the records from each base table individually, but I am not sure if there is an easier, more efficient way of doing this than what I am trying to attempt. I would like some guidance/advice if possible.

This is the only way I can think of of doing this:

1. Run a query that returns base table names from the view:

`DECLARE @vn as nvarchar(max) = 'dbo.TABLE_NAME'`

```
SELECT referenced_server_name, referenced_database_name, referenced_entity_name as SourceTable,referenced_minor_name as SourceColumn, referenced_minor_id as depnumber
             FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities (@vn, 'OBJECT')
             where referenced_minor_name  IS NOT NULL
             ORDER BY referenced_entity_name, referenced_minor_id
```

2. run `sp_helpconstraint N'<table_name>'`, which will give me a list of all default values/default constraint types, as well as the column names I will need to compare default values to the values in each table and determine whether or not a record should be deleted from them.

**Questions**

Is there an easier/more efficient way of trying to delete a record from a view?

NOTE: the full function I ended up writing has been added to the answers below for anyone interested in the answer

Comment: Are you talking about constructing a process that will work for any view, or for a specific view?

Comment: @jmcilhinney For any view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final working function I ended up using. (feel free to suggest a better way)

```
If DI.CommonDataFunctions.IsThisAView(BaseTableName, Globals.dif) Then
                Dim viewColumnNames As New List(Of String)
                Dim tableName As String
                Dim viewTables As New List(Of String)
                Dim isDefault
                Dim primaryKeyName As String

                //return table names from view
                Dim qp As New List(Of SqlParameter)
                qp.Add(New SqlParameter("@vn", $"dbo.{BaseTableName}"))
                Dim sql As String = "
            SELECT 
                referenced_entity_name as SourceTable,referenced_minor_name as SourceColumn
            FROM 
                sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities (@vn, 'OBJECT')
            WHERE 
                referenced_minor_name  IS NOT NULL
            ORDER BY 
                referenced_entity_name, referenced_minor_id"

                Using dr As New DataReader(Globals.dif.GetDBDetails)
                    Dim constraintKeys As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
                    Dim primaryKeyList As New List(Of Int32)
                    Dim table As String
                    dr.ExecuteReader(sql, qp)

                    Do While dr.Read
                        tableName = dr.Item("SourceTable").ToString.ToUpper.Trim
                        viewColumnNames.Add(dr.Item("SourceColumn").ToString.ToUpper.Trim)

                        If Not viewTables.Contains(tableName) Then
                            viewTables.Add(tableName)
                        End If
                    Loop

                    For Each table In viewTables
                        Dim columnName As String
                        Dim defaultConstraintValue
                        isDefault = True
                        table = table

                        dr.ExecuteReader("
                    SELECT Col.Column_Name from 
                        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Tab, 
                        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE Col 
                    WHERE 
                        Col.Constraint_Name = Tab.Constraint_Name
                    AND Col.Table_Name = Tab.Table_Name
                    AND Constraint_Type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
                    AND Col.Table_Name = '" + table + "'")

                        While dr.Read
                            primaryKeyName = dr.Item(0)
                        End While

                        //return default constraints
                        dr.ExecuteReader("
                    SELECT 
                        ColumnName = c.name,
                        TableName = t.name,
                        df.definition
                    FROM 
                        sys.default_constraints df
                    INNER JOIN 
                        sys.tables t ON df.parent_object_id = t.object_id
                    INNER JOIN 
                        sys.columns c ON c.object_id = df.parent_object_id AND df.parent_column_id = c.column_id
                    WHERE 
                        t.Name = N'" + table + "'")

                        While dr.Read
                            defaultConstraintValue = dr.Item("definition").ToString

                            //delete "(( ))" Or "( )" from default constraint
                            If defaultConstraintValue.StartsWith("((") AndAlso defaultConstraintValue.EndsWith("))") Then
                                defaultConstraintValue = defaultConstraintValue.Substring(0, defaultConstraintValue.Length - 2)
                                defaultConstraintValue = defaultConstraintValue.Substring(2)
                            ElseIf defaultConstraintValue.StartsWith("(") AndAlso defaultConstraintValue.EndsWith(")") Then
                                defaultConstraintValue = defaultConstraintValue.Substring(0, defaultConstraintValue.Length - 1)
                                defaultConstraintValue = defaultConstraintValue.Substring(1)
                            End If

                            If defaultConstraintValue.StartsWith("'") AndAlso defaultConstraintValue.EndsWith("'") Then
                                defaultConstraintValue = defaultConstraintValue.Substring(0, defaultConstraintValue.Length - 1)
                                defaultConstraintValue = defaultConstraintValue.Substring(1)

                                If Not IsNumeric(defaultConstraintValue) Then
                                    defaultConstraintValue = "'" + defaultConstraintValue + "'"
                                End If
                            End If

                            columnName = dr.Item("ColumnName").ToString.ToUpper.Trim

                            constraintKeys.Add(columnName, defaultConstraintValue)
                        End While
                    Next

                    Dim sql2 = "SELECT " + primaryKeyName + " FROM " + BaseTableName

                    If constraintKeys IsNot Nothing Then
                        Dim isFirstFilter = True
                        sql2 &= " WHERE "

                        For Each constraintKey In constraintKeys
                            If viewColumnNames.Contains(constraintKey.Key) AndAlso constraintKey.Key <> "FAMILY_UID" Then
                                If isFirstFilter = False Then
                                    sql2 &= " And "
                                End If

                                If IsNumeric(constraintKey.Value) Then
                                    Dim intConverted = CInt(constraintKey.Value)

                                    sql2 &= constraintKey.Key + " = " + intConverted.ToString + " "

                                    If isFirstFilter = True Then
                                        isFirstFilter = False
                                    End If
                                Else
                                    sql2 &= constraintKey.Key + " = " + constraintKey.Value + " "

                                    If isFirstFilter = True Then
                                        isFirstFilter = False
                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If

                    dr.ExecuteReader(sql2)

                    While dr.Read
                        primaryKeyList.Add(dr.Item(primaryKeyName))
                    End While

                    If primaryKeyList.Count > 0 Then
                        For Each table In viewTables
                            Dim isFirstFilter = True
                            Dim sql3 = "DELETE FROM " + table + " WHERE " + primaryKeyName + " IN ("

                            For Each primaryKey In primaryKeyList
                                sql3 &= primaryKey.ToString

                                If Not primaryKey = primaryKeyList(primaryKeyList.Count - 1) Then
                                    sql3 &= ", "
                                End If
                            Next

                            sql3 &= ")"

                            Using CEx As New CommandExecutor(Globals.dif)
                                CEx.ExecuteNonQuery(sql3)
                            End Using
                        Next
                    End If
                End Using
            End If
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure *if there is* an easier, more efficient way of doing this than what I am trying to attempt. I would like some guidance/advice if possible

TLDR; there isn't

---

You need to understand that a view is NOT data in the database; it's a stored SQL query that is run every time you select from the view.

It might even be the case that SQL Server takes your query and mixes it with the query that provides the view and optimizes them and runs them so it's not even necessarily the case that it runs the view query, gets all million records that the view represents, and then rifles through them looking for the one guy called Constantinople Ernhardt - SQL Server might consider it better to silently and transparently rewrite the query you gave  so it's planned and run completely differently to what you might think - it does this for every query, in a process called optimization.

Your view is:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS
SELECT * FROM Person p JOIN Address a on p.AddressId = a.Id
```

You write:

```
SELECT * FROM MyView WHERE Name = 'Abc' and HouseName = 'def'
```

You might think it does this (and conceptually, you're right):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT * FROM Person p JOIN Address a on p.AddressId = a.Id
) x WHERE Name = 'Abc' and HouseName = 'def'
```

But it probably gets rewritten to this:

```
SELECT * FROM Person p JOIN Address a on p.AddressId = a.Id WHERE Name = 'Abc' and HouseName = 'def'
```

---

So now that's out the way and you can see that a view is just a query on top of a table, that gets run every time you select from it - how do you delete data from a query?

You can't, because queries don't have data; they retrieve data from tables

**The only way to "delete data from a view" is to delete data from the table the view selects the data from**

You can only do this by `DELETE` statements on the table(s) concerned

There is a facility where you can write an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on a view, and then delete from the view, and SQL Server will run the trigger (which deletes from the underlying tables). It might look like you're deleteing data from the view, but really, you're just causing a mechanism to remove data from the underlying tables in the same way that the view is a mechanism that drags data out of those tables.

You could write a stored procedure that deletes data, but again, that's just a mechanism to delete data from the underlying table

Choose any method you like, as suits your business goals and desire for encapsulating your software in a certain way. For example, in the past I've had a software I couldn't change (lost the sourcecode or whatever) and it has been hard wired to `SELECT FROM users` or `DELETE FROM users` - we wanted the software to carry on working even though the users table was being renamed to members. We renamed the table then created a view called `users` that just did `SELECT * FROM members` - that allows the app to carry on working, reading data. Then we created `INSTEAD OF` triggers to update and delete data in the members table when the app attempted to do that operation to the `users` view (which the app still thought was a table)

---

So why is it so hard? Well the data that comes out of your view might not even relate to a table row any more. Here's a simple version:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS
SELECT MAX(SUBSTR(Name, 4, 999)) MaxFirstName FROM Person GROUP BY Gender
```

Suppose there were two people called `Mr Lee Smith` and `Ms Lee Smith`, you've taken the max of the function output and got `Lee Smith` and now you want to delete `Lee Smith` out of the person table by analyzing the view and deleting... *what* out of the Person table? Which record? Grouping mushed all the records up together. The MAX name of one an the MIN birthdate from another..

Here's another example, bit more ridiculous but imaginable:

```
  CREATE VIEW MyView AS
  SELECT name as x FROM person
  UNION
  SELECT street FROM address
```

This could easily produce the distinct value "Penny Lane" - but is it a person, or a road? Which should be deleted if we delete from this view where x = 'Penny Lane'

There isn't a magic bullet where you can run it and it will says "this table uses these 3 tables" so you can delete from them. It wouldn't even be a good premise. Your view might select from one data table and one lookup table, and deleting Gender type 1 from the lookup table just because you're deleting Donald Trump from the users table, would be a bad call

If you want to provide delete facilities on a view, you need to code something up; there isn't an automagical solution that can work out what data from what tables should be deleted and what should remain. Just imagine how difficult it would be to analyze a view that joins 9 tables, with a mix of join styles, plus another 8 lists of VALUES, 3 calls to a cross applied table valued function that parses some json, sling a couple of row generating recursive CTEs in there and a pivot too...

Absolutely no chance that anyone would have written the magic button to pick all that apart into "work out the list of base tables and what data should be deleted from which to satisfy `DELETE FROM MyView WHERE output_of_parsing_function = 'Hello'`

Comment: Thanks for your thoroughly detailed answer. Each row in a table/view has an id column with a unique id. This is why it is possible to do this. I'm guessing you probably didn't understand my question properly. I have written the function I ended up creating as an answer to this thread